# how to break the loop if condition satisfies in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of ints consisting of

```
{1,2,3,1,2,1,5,1,2,1,1}
```

I like retrieve all 1 located before 5 . I need skip all other items after 5 .The End list will be

```
{1,1,1}
```

How can i do this using linq?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list 
            = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 2, 1, 1 };

        var filteredList 
            = list.TakeWhile(i => i != 5)
                    .Where(j => j == 1);
    }
}
```

The [`TakeWhile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534804.aspx) method yields all elements from the original sequence up until an element fails the predicate.  So in this case we are yielding all the numbers from `list` until we reach one that equals 5.

Once we have done this we can simply filter down the resulting sequence to just the 1's using [`Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Example showing the differences in laziness between Andrew Hare's solution and Saeed's solution.

```
class Program
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> TestData()
    {
        while (true)
            yield return 5;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> AndrewHare(IEnumerable<int> xs)
    {
        return xs.TakeWhile(i => i != 5)
                 .Where(j => j == 1);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<int> Saeed(IEnumerable<int> xs)
    {
        bool find5 = false;
        return xs.Where(p => p == 1 && !(find5 = (p == 5) ? true : find5));
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();

        watch.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            foreach (var x in AndrewHare(TestData())) ;
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        watch.Restart();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            foreach (var x in Saeed(TestData())) ;
        }
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't understand why you provided this here and why you rich upvote by copy pasting my code. And I didn't, it's like a friendship relation between two people here.